# Слово «обруша́я»

Tags: лексика, словообразование, деепричастия

Не нашёл в словарях такого слова. Собственно, почему его нет? "Обрушив" — это уже сделав, "обрушая" — ещё делая, по аналогии с "разрушив" и "разрушая". Почему нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Современная фора глагола совершенного вида - **"обрушивать"**, соответственно деепричастие - **"обрушивая"**. Законное и известное словарям.

*"Обрушая"* возможно только от *"обрушать"*, но эта форма совершенно вышла из употребления.

Аналогия с **"разрушать", "разрушая"** не проходит, эти формы абсолютно современны и продуктивны. Вот *"разрушивать"* грамматике не известно вовсе.

Answer (score 3):

[**обруша́ть**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/200518)
**I**. *несов. перех.*
**1.** Разламывая, разрушая, заставлять упасть; обваливать (обрушивать 1).
**2.** Направлять, устремлять, низвергать массу чего-либо на кого-либо или на что-либо с силой (обрушивать 2).
**3.** *перен.* Направлять, устремлять на кого-либо всю силу каких-либо чувств или забот, тягот, обвинений и т. п. (обрушивать 3)
**II**. *несов. перех.*
Очищать зерно от шелухи и раздроблять, изготовляя крупу.

Из ответа: *"Обрушая" возможно только от "обрушать", но эта форма совершенно вышла из употребления.*
Я бы не стала высказываться столь категорично.
И сам глагол, и деепричастие, от него образованное, все-таки используются в современном языке.

*"ПриватБанк" никто не собирается **обрушать** — он занимает слишком большое и важное место в украинской финансовой системе* (Ю. Бутусов [2016]).

*Он ревет, как сотни тигров,

**Обрушая** плоть земли,

Собирая слёзы мира,

Ослабляя ледники...*
Р. Сиразиев. Водопад [2018]

*Требуется филигранная работа с педалью газа, чтобы мягко перевалить язык дюны, **обрушая** тяжестью машины массу песка* (Э. Хайруллин [2013]).

*...Марина ответила извиняющимся тоном, мысленно **обрушая** на Костю, укатившего в центр по делам, все мыслимые и немыслимые кары* (И. Вардунас [2013]).